# can't display anything to the terminal with dbms_output.put_line and serveroutput on

Tags: plsql, oracle11g, sqlplus, dbms-output

The below bloc executes fine in sqldeveloper but when i try to automate my script with the terminal, the DBMS does not print anything. note that i already tried :  `set serveroutput on`, `set feedback 0` , `DBMS_OUTPUT.ENABLE (buffer_size => NULL)` but still nothing printed. 
need your help please.thanks

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;  
DECLARE
   var1 varchar2(1000);
BEGIN
   SELECT var2 INTO var1 FROM my_table WHERE name='name_1' ;
   dbms_output.put_line('result: ' || var1 );
END;
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "automate my script with the terminal"?  What terminal, and automate it how?

Comment: i mean, i want to execute my script saved in txt file throw cmd with START /b /wait ...

Comment: So are you calling sqlplus.exe from a Windows cmd prompt?

Comment: If you are using sqlplus you need to put a slash "/" after the anonymous block or it is never executed.

Comment: @BrianLeach yes exactly it works thank you so much for your help